# NJ Transit Weekly Pass

Tags: trains, tickets

I just purchased a Weekly pass for South Amboy-Ny Penn in the mobile app. Does it work in both directions or just the one? I opened the ticket on my phone and it just says from south amboy to NY penn. But on the website, it says that Weekly passes offer unlimed travel between two stations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works in both directions.

NJ Transit train tickets and passes have been direction-less since the elimination of their off-peak round-trip ticket in 2010.